# QGIS transparency layer export to pdf not working

Tags: qgis, layers, export, pdf, transparency-opacity

I have in a drawing polygon layer with a degree of transparency setting. However, after exporting to PDF a layer is not transparent anymore. Where is the problem? I use QGIS 3.16.

Comment: Please provide your layer symbology and your export settings.

Comment: I just tried exporting a map to PDF with transparency in four different ways - on the layer, the blending, the blend mode, and the fill colour. All exported to PDF with correct transparency via Project... Import/Export... Export Map to PDF. Can't see any options in that that might not preserve transparency. What precisely did you do?

Comment: Solved. I used transparency in layer setting - layer drawing.